# adding texts in to textbox by selecting the value from dropdown

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

i have two dropdown one in ajax and other one is in html i want to add the value of dropdown in to textbox from each of the dropdown.how to add the selected value in to the text box??
my code is

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ListOfEmployees',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, e) {
                    $('#DepartmentId').append('<option value="' + e.DepatID + '">' + e.DepartmentName);
                      var myValue = $(this).val();
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

        <td>
            <%=Html.DropDownList("ForModalityID", new SelectList(Model.ModalityList, "ModalityID", "ModalityDisplayName"))%>
        </td>

         <td>Name </td><td>
    <%= Html.TextArea("sfv") %>
    </td>
```

i am new in this field.i am not able to add the selected value of dropdown in text area....
Help me ....thanks

Comment: Did my asnwer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
       $('#IdOfText').html($(this).val();)
});
```

You bind a `.change()` event to the `<select>` which gets the value of that `<select>` and sets it as the html for you text box.

`$.html()`: http://api.jquery.com/html/

`$.change()`: http://api.jquery.com/change/

`$.val()`: http://api.jquery.com/val/